# How to know when data is inserted in table using room?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am using room With kotlin coroutines to manage database. I need to access data stored in database just after storing it in next activity but it is giving a error as data is not stored yet. How to know when data is inserted in table?

```
wordViewModel.insert(it.body()!!.guests[0])
val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: What is the signature of `insert`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create a Content observer on your model entity. You can lookup a tutorials online. Basically, the content observer is what its name suggests, it observes the content and notifies you if there is new "content" available (in this case a change in the database).

Other, and, I'd say, preferable way is to utilize LiveData. In your `Dao`, you just add method with the similar signature:

```
@Query(/*put your select query here*/)
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<YourModelClass>>
```

then, in your activity, or wherever you want to observe changes, you call

```
yourDao.getAll().observe(this, Observer { /* your observer implementation */ })
```